# Bitbucket SSH commit isn't pulling username and email from public-private keypair through agent forwarding

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I have an interesting problem here. There is an EC2 server set up that multiple people can connect to where there is a git repository connected to Bitbucket. I have it currently set up so that the repository is using SSH instead of HTTPS, that way each person can use their own SSH private keys to connect instead of utilizing one person through HTTPS.

The SSH key is being forwarded from the local machine to the remote machine through agent forwarding. That is working fine and everyone can successfully interact with Bitbucket.

I may be misunderstanding but from what I know, git should be pulling credentials from Bitbucket and using that when making commits. Despite utilizing SSH for the repository, I am being prompted for my username and email. Providing the username and email will persist for anyone who connects to the EC2 instance and pushes, which in Bitbucket, makes it seem like one person is making all of the commits.

Something must be done wrong, but I am not entirely sure what I could be missing.

Here is relevant information:

- Public keys are associated in Bitbucket under Personal Settings
- Local SSH config:

  ```
  Host remote
      HostName remote.com
      User onlyuser
      ServerAliveInterval 30
      ForwardAgent yes
  ```
- Remote server git config file:

  ```
  [remote "origin"]
      url = git@bitbucket.org:account/marketingwebsitetheme.git
      fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
  ```
- Running `ssh -T` gives me something slightly different than the traditional message that is given with the username

  ```
  $ ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
  authenticated via ssh key.

  You can use git to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled
  ```

Comment: I think you are confusing git config `user.name` (a users name, not their username) and `user.email` with actual authentication. They have absolutely nothing to do with each other. Unless you have plugins active in BitBucket that requires commit authors to match the user performing the push - you can make a commit appear to come from literally anyone as long as you know their name and email.

Comment: Sorry, my understanding was that the git `user.name` and `user.email` would be pulled from Bitbucket via SSH. I misunderstood. Thank you!